# How do I force NetworkManager to update /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: redhat, networkmanager

If I add a new DNS server using `nmcli connection modify eth0 +ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8`, I still have to update `/etc/resolv.conf` for the resolver to pick up the changes, right? So how do I force the update?

The only way I found was restarting the network service: `/etc/init.d/network restart`. Is there a less invasive way -- a `nmcli` command, perhaps?

Comment: What do you want the NetworkManager to update it with?

Comment: Added some clarifications to the question.

Comment: Since my nmcli does not have this modify command, I can only guess :) Try: resolvconf -u

Comment: @KonradGajewski If having resolconnf installed, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

based on http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-configure-ipv4-addresses/

```
nmcli connection up eth0
```

run after mod calls, worked for me.

P.S.
you can use "nmcli -p connection show eth0" to see the configured vs active settings

Comment: Save your fingers! `connection` can be abbreviated, all the way to `c`.

Comment: Interestingly, the help article by RH suggests `nmcli c reload` which didn't work for changing DNS entries.

Answer (score 2):

Add following to interface configuration file (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX`):

```
PEERDNS=yes
DNS1=1.2.3.4
DNS2=1.2.3.4
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

bring interface up:

```
ifup ethX
```

Answer (score 2):

If nmcli is NOT available (for example when NetworkManager is not installed) there is another way (handy on older Linux 6 distros) to add and remove new settings at will from /etc/resolv.conf without restarting network and without manually editing /etc/resolv.conf file.  The steps are:

1. Create a virtual NIC following the steps as described [here](https://arstech.net/create-virtual-interface-centos-6-linux/) or any other reference on creating a virtual NIC (e.g. ifcfg-eth0:0).

   Note: I also change BOOTPROTO=none and NM_CONTROLLED=no in the ifcfg-eth0:0 file.

2. Add whatever settings to the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0 file are desired to apply to the /etc/resolv.conf file.  Example:

> DNS1="8.8.8.8 7.7.7.7"

> DOMAIN="urdomain1.com urdomain2.com"

3. The new settings in the ifcfg-eth0:0 can be "switched on" (added) in the /etc/resolv.conf by simply running the following command:

> sudo ifup ifcfg-eth0:0

The new settings can be "switched off" (removed) by running:

> sudo ifdown ifcfg-eth0:0

and this method should work on any distro whether it has nmcli or not.  This is arguably a variation on Giomac's answer, but it has the additional advantage that this VNIC can be brought up and down without affecting anything except that it will update the /etc/resolv.conf in both (up and down) directions.

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you will need to identify your network interface (i.e eth0)

```
# nmcli  conn
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE
eth0  74315f7c-1573-4150-9c0e-e06ad28cac95  802-3-ethernet  eth0
#

# nmcli conn edit eth0

===| nmcli interactive connection editor |===

Editing existing '802-3-ethernet' connection: 'eth0'

Type 'help' or '?' for available commands.
Type 'describe [<setting>.<prop>]' for detailed property description.

You may edit the following settings: connection, 802-3-ethernet (ethernet), 802-1x, ipv4, ipv6, dcb
nmcli> print ipv4.dns-search
ipv4.dns-search: mydomain.linux.com
nmcli>
nmcli> set ipv4.dns-search mylinuxdomain.com,anotherdomain.com
nmcli>
nmcli> save permanent
```

Then restart your network.
I use nmcli to do so:
 1. To bring down

```
# nmcli conn down eth0
```

2. To bring up

```
# nmcli conn up eth0
```

Comment: You *do* *not* need to bring the connection down. Just do a `nmcli conn up eth0` to save `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Careful while executing "nmcli conn down eth0"  , if you are using an azure vm then your connection to that machine will go off...

Answer (score 1):

- Show available device to configure: `nmcli c s`

  You will need the NAME or the UUID of that list. Let's assume the connection name is `eth0`.
- Show the current IPv4 DNS settings of eth0: `nmcli c s eth0 | grep ipv4.dns:`
- Set IPv4 DNS settings to Google DNS entries 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4: `sudo nmcli c m eth0 ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"`
- Save changes to system files (like /etc/resolv.conf, etc.) with: `sudo nmcli c up eth0`

Bonus:

- Do the whole thing to a remote server over ssh: `ssh remote-server 'sudo nmcli c m eth0 ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" && sudo nmcli c up eth0'`

Answer (score 0):

Searched quite some time for the correct answer, and found it in another stack overflow post ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/974482)). This annoying thing is a known systemd bug, so you need to recreate the symlink pointing to the correct file.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
reboot
```

Before you do this, check if the file contains the correct DNS entries:

```
sudo cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

## RHEL 7

How to set DNS in CentOS/RHEL 7 & prevent NetworkManager from overwriting /etc/resolv.conf?

Source : [enter link description here][1]

## Step 1

The NetworkManager configuration is located here: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf Open this file using vim or your favorite text editor.

Search for the [main] section in this file. It should look something like this:

...
[main]
#plugins=ifcfg-rh,ibft
...
Add dns=none just after the [main] tag like this:

```
...
[main]
dns=none
#plugins=ifcfg-rh,ibft
...
```

Go ahead and save the file.

## Step 2

Let’s restart the NetworkManager.service service so that it picks up the changes we made to the configuration.

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
Note that the service name NetworkManager.service is case-sensitive.

## Step 3

Now, let’s add our nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf

Open this file in you favorite text editor and specify the name servers as follows:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

## RHEL 6

CentOS / RHEL : DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf change after a reboot/network service restart. How to make them permanent

Source : [https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-dns-servers-in-etcresolv-conf-change-after-a-rebootnetwork-service-restart-how-to-make-them-permanent/][2]

You would face this issue after a reboot or a network service restart. This usually happens as the scripts /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-post and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifdown-post checks for the parameters “RESOLV_MODS=no” or “PEERDNS=no” in the network interface configuration file such as /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*. If these either of these parameters are not present, it will replace the contents of /etc/resolv.conf with /etc/resolv.conf.save. By default, PEERDNS and RESOLV_MODS are null.

1. The /etc/resolv.conf file will be overwritten if any network interfaces use DHCP for activation. To prevent this, ensure such interfaces have PEERDNS=no set in their ifcfg file, for example:

   ```
    #cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
    TYPE=Ethernet
    DEVICE=eth0
    BOOTPROTO=dhcp
    PEERDNS=no
   ```
2. The ifcfg-file directives DNS1 and DNS2 can also lead to modification of resolv.conf. To prevent this, either remove said directives or use chattr(1) to make resolv.conf immutable to changes, i.e.:

   ```
    #chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
   ```